# Silverstripe File relation in ModelAdmin doesnt publish

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Im using SilverStripe4 and the ModelAdmin to manage DataObjects.

The DataObject has a has_one on File. Everything works so far but on frontend controller the File relation has an empty object.

I see that the file is not in the File_Live table, so i guess its not published and therefor its not found on the frontend controller.

How can i publish File relations from the ModelAdmin?
Basically when a file is uploaded it should be automatically published.

I guess if i use versioned DataObjects i would still need something like this: https://github.com/drzax/silverstripe-bits/tree/master/VersionedModelAdmin
to have publish mechanism on ModelAdmin.

Or is there something builtin in SS4?
Would this cascade down to File relations as well?

**Edit:**
regarding versioned DataObjects there is a built in publish button in SS4
just use:

```
private static $extensions = [
    Versioned::class,
];

private static $versioned_gridfield_extensions = true;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the following to your DataObject:

```
private static $owns = ['FileRelationName'];
```

Example with a relation:

```
private static $has_one = ['File' => File::class];
private static $owns = ['File'];
```

Any related object that is being declared as "owned" in this way will be published with the `DataObject` itself.

Comment: Does this work only when the owning DataObject is versioned?

Comment: @ivoba AFAIK it also works if your DataObject isn't versioned

Comment: reading this, I remember I've stumbled over it here: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/7359
It's a 4.1 milestone, but you bothy say it works now with 4.0

Comment: @munomono i need to add: i added versioning to my dataobjects. so i cant really say it works for non versionened dataobjects.